# parsing string with substring

Tags: java

what is the best way to parse string

Example

```
SomeName_Some1_Name2_SomeName3
```

I want to get out `SomeName`. What is the best way to do? With `substring` and calculationg positions or is another better way

Comment: Do you want just the first `SomeName`, the second `SomeName` ignoring the 3 or `Some1_Name2` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match pattern `SomeName` for extracting-

```
        String str= "SomeName_Some1_Name2_SomeName3";
        Pattern ptrn= Pattern.compile("SomeName");
        Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Split it by underscore `_` using method `split()`
- Get index # 0 from returning array from previous step

Comment: What about `SomeName` portion from last token `SomeName3`?

Comment: Did OP mention anywhere that `SomeName` will be taken out of `SomeName3` also?

Comment: OP said: 'I want to get out SomeName' `SomeName3` _includes_ `SomeName`. It's obvious though that the question isn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

If you know the delimiter then you can just try this:

```
System.out.println("SomeName_Some1_Name2_SomeName3".split("_")[0]);
```

See also: Javadoc of [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your configuration and whether you're interested in the other fields.
In that case, go for splitting the string using the _ separator.

In case you just want a part of the string, I'ld just go for substringing in combination with indexOf('_').

In case you want all Occurences you could also find all occurences of 'someName' in your text.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex and Pattern Matcher API to get SomeName.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
String str = "SomeName_Some1_Name2_SomeName3";
String newStr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("_"));
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Output:

```
SomeName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "SomeName_Some1_Name2_SomeName3";
String output = str.split ( "_" ) [ 0 ];
```

you will get your output as SomeName.

Answer (score 0):

```
String your_String =  "SomeName_Some1_Name2_SomeName3";
your_String = your_String.split("_")[0];
Log.v("log","your string  "+ your_String);
```